# How to set precision (or round) float values in a Pandas DataFrame when using `df.style.background_gradient()`?

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to round the numbers of a data frame and put it into a table then save it as a jpeg so I can text it out daily as a leaderboard.  I am able to accomplish everything but when I create by table in style.background_gradient() it adds a lot of 0's.

I usually have been using the round(table,0) function but it doesn't work on this particular table type.  Any suggestions would be appreciated! This is the data frame below pre style.
[image]

Once I add the following code it turns it to this
`styled = merged.round(2).style.background_gradient()`

[image]

I would love to get rid of the zero's if possible.

Answer (score 3):

This worked for me:

```py
merged.style.set_precision(2).background_gradient(cmap = 'Blues')
```

Comment: Getting a message that this is deprecated in favor of `Styler.format(precision=..)`

Answer (score 0):

If there are `Nan` in a column the dtype is `float` and the notebook will display the data with a comma (also if the first decimal is zero). The solution I suggest is to transform the dtype of these columns in `'Int32'` or `'Int32'` (`int` raise an error)

```
for col in data.columns:
    if data[col].dtype == 'float64':
        data[col].astype('Int32')
```

Answer (score 0):

I've had this problem with a correlation matrix:

```
# this matrix has 2 decimals
correlation_matrix = round(numeric_columns.corr(),2)

# but when I Apply a gradient color scheme to the correlation matrix it prints 6 decimals.
styled_matrix = correlation_matrix.style.background_gradient(cmap='RdYlGn', vmin=-1, vmax=1)

# so instead, I need to add this format(precision=2) into the statement as such
styled_matrix = correlation_matrix.style.format(precision=2).background_gradient(cmap='RdYlGn', vmin=-1, vmax=1)

# so you should be able to use:
styled = merged.round(2).format(precision=2).style.background_gradient()
```